# Why am I getting this error? dest.on is not a function - using gulp-file-include

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am getting an Error of `TypeError: dest.on is not a function`. When running this task, I can't figure out what could be wrong.

```
var fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var paths = {
  templates : './templates/'
}

//file include: grab partials from templates and render out html files

gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {

return gulp.src(paths.templates + '*.tpl.html')
 .pipe(fileinclude)
 .pipe(rename({
  extname: ""
 }))
.pipe(rename({
  extname: ".html"
 }))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This line:

```
.pipe(fileinclude)
```

Should be this:

```
.pipe(fileinclude())
```

Comment: thank you very much cant believe i missed that lol.

Would you know why when i tried to use path.join(paths.templates, '*.tpl.html)

it would give error path is undefined

Comment: You probably forgot `var path = require('path')`.

Comment: Dude thank you so much , I'm still learning but slowly getting things everything working like a charm . have a great day ✌